# Mounting hard drive via bash

Tags: bash, mount, scripts

I'm trying to write a bash script which checks which sda/sdb/sdc my hard drive happens to be associated with and mounts my hard drive based on whichever one it is.

```
if (( `sudo fdisk -l | grep /dev/sdc | grep "1.8 TiB"` )) 
        then
            echo sdc1 with 2TiB found.
            sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/2tbOrange/
fi
```

I'm getting the following "division by 0" error, and I can't figure out why.

```
 ((: Disk /dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors : division by 0 (error token is "dev/sdc: 1.8 TiB, 2000365289472 bytes, 3906963456 sectors ")
```

Comment: Try this line instead:  `if [[ $(fdisk -l | grep /dev/sdc | grep "1.8 TiB") ]]`

Comment: However, this line might fail if you leave a USB drive in when booting up as it can change the drive designation.  Look into using `blkid` and getting the UUID of the drive instead and mounting that as the UUIDs don't change unless the drive is formatted.

Comment: @Terance I'd say [[ and command substitution aren't necessary. The exit status of pipeline is of the last command, so with `grep -q` it'd be silent and reliant on exit status which all that's necessary. And I think your idea with UUID is far better

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I know it isn't necessary, it was only a quick suggestion.  Fixing simple things like this is how I started on more complicated and more effecient ways of doing things.  I am not here to rewrite scripts for people.  I gave up on that due to someone wanting me to write their whole thing for them.

Comment: @Terrance Yeah, understandable. There are users who want more and more, and eventually it's like writing whole script in the comments. I think I just get more and more comfortable with shell and just using the minimum necessary methods

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting that error is because double parentheses `((...))` are for arithmetic, so a slash indicates division. For more details, see [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/117037) on Unix & Linux.

As discussed in the comments, you could use `grep -q`. It returns true if a match is found, and false otherwise.

```
if sudo fdisk -l | grep /dev/sdc | grep -q "1.8 TiB"; then ...
```

That said, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The code you wrote does not do what you describe. From a quick search, it looks the best solution is to use `mount -L` or `mount -U` to mount by the filesystem label or UUID, respectively. You don't need to parse the output of `fdisk -l`, and you don't need an if-statement. If you need more details, let me know; you may need to ask a new question.